# res.render() function rendering an ejs page doesn't refresh the UI, but the ejs page get called

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a list of resources which needs to be filtered based on the location. I have a form to filter and on click of a button, the data is filtered based on the location. I have an AJAX request and it sends a post request to /filterresources and the data matching that criteria is also fetched from the db and the resourcefilter.ejs is rendered using res.render() as given below:

resourcefilter.js:

```
    router.post('/filterresources',function(req,res,next){
        var category = req.body.category;
        User.find({_id: {$ne: req.user._id}},(err,user) => {
            if(err) throw err;
            if(user)
            {
                db.findAll(Resource,{category:category})
                    .then(function(data){
                        res.render('resourcefilter',{title:"Steel Smiling",user:req.user,header:true,navbar:true,resources:data});
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        next(err);
                    });
            }
            else {
                throw(err);
            }
        });


    });

The problem here is, as the records are fetched the UI doesn't get updated even when new ejs page is called. It still retains the previous page UI. But any console.log() statements in the new ejs page gets displayed.
```

resourcefilter.ejs: All console statements in this get printed without any issues but UI is not refreshed. Any help is much appreciated.

```
<% layout('layout/layout') %>


<div class="container user-form py-5">
    <br>
    <%if(user.role == 'Administrator'){ console.log(user.role);%>
    <a href="/resourceupload" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="float: right" ><span>Create Resource</span></a>
    <%}%>
    </br>
    <span class="site-logo my-3">Our Resources</span>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 offset-lg-2" style="margin-left: 33%">
        <form id="filter-resources" class="mt-5">
            <div>
                <select class="custom-select" name="category" id="category">
                    <option selected>Select a location:</option>
                    <option value="Pittsburgh">Pittsburgh</option>
                    <option value="Allegheny County">Allegheny County</option>
                    <option value="Pennsylvania">Pennsylvania</option>
                    <option value="Outside Pennsylvania">Outside Pennsylvania</option>
                </select>
                <input class="filter" name="filter-resources" type="submit" value="Filter">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    </form>

    <div class="container" style="margin-top: 2%;">

        <div class="row">
            <% for(var i=0;i<resources.length;i++){ console.log("Hello"+resources.length); %>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">

                <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">

                    <div class="mainflip">

                        <div class="frontside">

                            <div class="card-custom">
                                <% console.log("Image"+resources[i].image);%>
                                <div class="card-body text-center">
                                    <img src="<%= resources[i].image %>" alt="" class="img-resources">
                                    <div class="card-title"><b><%= resources[i].name%></b></div>
                                    <div id="greetings" class="card-title"><textarea readonly class="resourceDesc"><%= resources[i].description%></textarea></div>
                                    <a href ="#"  class="card-title"></a>
                                    <a href = <%= resources[i].website%> id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">
                                        Read More!</a>

                                    <br></br>         </div>
                            </div>
                            <br></br>
                        </div>



                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>


            <% } %>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AJAX function to call to /filterresources:

```
function filter_resources(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var category = $('#category :selected').text();
    console.log(category);
    const button = this.children[this.children.length - 1];

    //Form Handling with ajax

    $.ajax({

        url: '/filterresources',
        type: 'post',
        data: {category: category},
        dataType: 'json',

    });

    function refreshDiv() {     
        document.getElementById("getelebyid").innerHTML = "Some <strong>HTML</strong> <em>string</em>" ;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looking at your form I don't see an action being called to the /filterresources URL, also no method. Are you sending the request in a separate AJAX function?

Comment: Yes the /filter resources is called using a separate AJAX function

Comment: Can you post the AJAX function?

Comment: I have added the AJAX function above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ejs, js and html code are correct, the problem is that your AJAX function does not refresh the page's content, it only retrieves the content. There are 2 solutions: Either, in the EJS, change from "render" to "send" and then in the AJAX callback use the value returned as innerHTML for some element, or do a form submit, and not a jquery post. The form submit will cause a page reload.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any errors from your server you can do a workaround with the front end:

```
$.ajax({

        url: '/filterresources',
        type: 'post',
        data: {category: category},
        dataType: 'json',

    }).then(() => location.reload());
```

That will refresh your page when the request finishes.

Answer (score 1):

location.reload() didn't work in this context because the filtered data needs to be passed on to the page. Hence, instead of using res.render(), i used res.send as suggested. Please find the below code:

filterresources.js

```
router.post('/filterresources',function(req,res,next){
    var category = req.body.category;
    User.find({_id: {$ne: req.user._id}},(err,user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        if(user)
        {
            var user = req.user._id;
            console.log(user);
            db.findAll(Resource,{category:category})
                .then(function(data){
                    res.send({msg: data, success: true,user: user });
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    next(err);
                });
        }
        else {
            throw(err);
        }

    });
});
```

AJAX function:

```
function filter_resources(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var category = $('#category :selected').text();
    console.log(category);
    const button = this.children[this.children.length - 1];

    //Form Handling with ajax

    $.ajax({
        url: '/filterresources',
        type: 'post',
        data: {category: category},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (response) {
            if (!response.success) {
                window.alert(response.msg);
            }
            if (response.success) {
                var resource = response.msg;
                var userInfo = response.user;
                $('#resfilter').html(""); // reset the contents in the div
                var html = `<div class="row">`;
                for(var i=0;i<resource.length;i++) {
                    html += `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                                <div class="mainflip"> <div class="frontside"> <div class="card-custom">
                                <div class="card-body text-center">`;
                    html += `<img src="${resource[i].image}" alt="Mental Health Resource" class="img-resources">`;
                    html += `<div class="card-title"><b>${resource[i].name}</b></div>`;
                    html += `<div id="greetings" class="card-title"><textarea readonly class="resourceDesc">${resource[i].description}</textarea></div>`;
                    html += `<a href ="#"  class="card-title"></a>`;
                    html += `<a href = ${resource[i].website} id="singlebutton" name="singlebutton" class="btn btn-primary">Read More!</a>`;
                    html += `<br>`;
                    html += `</br></div></div><br></br></div></div></div></div>`;
                }
                    html += `</div></div></div></div>`;
                    }
                    document.querySelector('#resfilter').innerHTML = html; // add the html content to the div which was earlier reset
                }
                })
}
```